# How do I build Python 3.8 on Travis CI?

Tags: python-3.x, travis-ci

When I follow the [instructions provided](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/#python-37-and-higher) to build Python 3.8 on Travis using, for example

```
language: python 

matrix:
  include:
    - name: "Python 3.8 dev"
      python: 3.8-dev
      dist: trusty
      env: PYTHON=python3 PIP=pip3  # Unnecessary on Lunix
```

[I get](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-py/jobs/524630250)

```
3.8-dev is not installed; attempting download
Downloading archive: https://storage.googleapis.com/travis-ci-language-archives/python/binaries/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/python-3.8-dev.tar.bz2
0.06s$ curl -sSf -o python-3.8-dev.tar.bz2 ${archive_url}
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Unable to download 3.8-dev archive. The archive may not exist. Please consider a different version.
```

How do I build Python 3.8 on Travis CI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the dist to `xenial`, as that is required for 3.7 or higher.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/#python-37-and-higher